# $watch or $watchCollection not working for object which is referenced by ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined an items object inside the main app controller which has 3 Boolean items. I am sending this object to a directive which has isolated scope. In this directive, I am iterating over the received object with ng-repeat and creating check-boxes with ng-model = item in items object.

But I am not able to watch the changes on items object (done by ng-model on the directive). The $watchCollection which I have put doesn't seem to work.

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = {
    item1: true,
    item2: false,
    item3: true
  };

  $scope.$watchCollection('items', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal, newVal);
  });

});

myApp.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    template: "<div ng-repeat='(item,val) in items'><label><input type='checkbox' ng-model='val'/>{{item}}</label></div>"
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <test-directive items="items"></test-directive>
</div>
```

However, if inside the directive HTML, I don't use ng-repeat and create individual check-boxes manually, then $watchCollection correctly watches the changes:

```
<div>
  <label>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='items.item1' />Item1</label>
  <label>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='items.item2' />Item2</label>
  <label>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='items.item3' />Item3</label>
</div>
```

Below is the JSFiddle link of the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/rishabh1990/0kb6tezd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$watchCollection** will work only if your collection's data changes ( added, removed), not if the inner data changes.

For watching the inner data changes, you msut write

```
  $scope.$watch('items', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal, newVal);
  }, true);
```

**EDITED** See here

https://jsfiddle.net/5bf3v0xj/

**Why**

```
 $scope.items = [
    {name: 'item1', value: true},
    {name: 'item2', value: false},
    {name: 'item3', value: true}
  ];
```

and not a

```
 $scope.items = {
        item1: true},
        item2: false},
        item3: true}
      }
```

**EXPLANATION**

Because `ng-repeat` creates it's own `scope` and copies the primitives values.

**string** behave as a primitive value, so `ng-repeat` will have **it's own copies** of this variables.And because you are **watching** to the **originals ` not copies**, it will **never** fire.

And one more thing: it is a good style to have a `.` in the **ng-repeat's variable** :
 like 
`ng-model='item.value` in the code.

Comment: But even the $watch is not working. Please see the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rishabh1990/0kb6tezd/12/

Comment: You converted the single items object into an array of item objects, moving the object property names into a property value of "name" property of individual item objects. But can't there be a solution without changing the data-structure itself?

Comment: @Rishabh no, it copies the value.If the value is a reference type it will have only the reference's copy, but if it is a primitive variable, it will copy the whole value, so the address of the value will be changed. See the explanation

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. But you wrote "string behave as a primitive value, so ng-repeat will have it's own copies of this variables.". I haven't used any string, but object with boolean items. Can u please tell which string you are referring to?

Comment: @Rishabh I don't refer to any string, only example, but know that string not a primitive value but it behave as a primitive value